# problem to get data from firestore. generate an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final CollectionReference usersCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future addUserData(String email, bool won) async {
    return await usersCollection
        .doc()
        .set({'email': email, 'won': won, 'dateTime': DateTime.now()});
  }

  Future getUserList() async {
    List itemsList = [];

    try {
      await usersCollection.get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
          itemsList.add(element.data);
        });
      });
      return itemsList;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

got me an error

> Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]' Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':. Tried calling:  Found:  => Map<String, dynamic>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to map the data that you are returning in the forEach loop as like this =>

```
Future<List<BrandModel>> getAllBrands() async {
 List<BrandModel> brands = [];
 Query q = _firestore.collection('brands');
 QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await q.get();
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
    result.id;
    brands.add(BrandModel.fromJson(result.data()));
  });
 return brands;
```

}